# Track movements of 500 objects in one single room

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, accelerometer, bluetooth-low-energy

Let's say we have a room with a size of approximately 300 sqm. In this room we have 500 objects that are tagged with beacons having accelerometers. Is there any way to process the produced data of these beacons with a kind of hub? Thought about Bluetooth Low Energy but that only supports a few connections at the same time. Also thought about Wifi but I don't know if a hub would be able to handle 500 Wifi connections + battery life of the beacons would be much better with Bluetooth I guess. Any ideas very welcome.

Comment: All that I can offer is an opinion and SE is clear about questions soliciting opinions: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Look up ZigBee. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175647/maximum-number-of-zigbee-devices)

Comment: Since I shouldn't give product recommendations won't mention this https://www.zebra.com/us/en/solutions/location-solutions/enabling-technologies/dart-uwb.html Expensive but easily does what you want. If I did mention it I would point out that the only change zebra have made since they purchased the company that designed it 10 years ago was to increase the price and change the paint colour. They can't update it because all the people who understood how it worked left as quickly as they could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth is a protocol layer on top of the IEEE 802.15.4 physical layer.

You can buy surface mount transceiver modules such as the MRF24J40M(A/B/C/D/E) that implement the 802.15.4 physical an MAC layers.  The modules have a SPI bus interface.  Some modules have integrated antennas in them, others have options for external antenna.

You could make your own protocol directly on top of the 802.15.4 layer.

The 802.15.4 MAC layer and MRF24J40xxx supports the following...

1. Packets of up to 255 bytes.
2. Carrier sense with collision avoidance
3. Acknowledgment of packets, or transmission without acknowledgement if lower latency is required.
4. Automatic retry mechanisms with random backoff delays.
5. Simultaneous use of thousands of addresses per network ID.
6. Simultaneous use of thousands of network IDs.
7. Up to 15 radio frequencies in the 2.4 GHz band. The MRF24J40 cau use any one of these 15 channels at one time. If congestion gets bad you can use multiple MRF24J40s in the hub to support receiving data from multiple channels concurrently.
8. Typial packet latency of just a few ms.
9. 250 kbps data rate.  The MRF24J40 also supports a non-standard high speed mode if you need more data rate on fewer channels.
10. Error correction codes to improve probability of correct reception.
11. Automatic CRC generation and calculation on each packet.

The MRF24J40 can sleep at only 10 uA of power, wake up and transmit, and then go back to sleep. I have developed radio boards using it that use only a few hundred uA of average current.  In cases with lower transmission rates the current could be much lower.

http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/en535967

Each module costs around $6.08 in large quantities.

Answer (score 1):

Any sensor telemetry design must define the inputs, outputs and functions with a priority on bandwidth sharing, latency requirements and algorithms for bandwidth reduction based on content needs.

Until this is done, the answer is unknown if there is sufficient capacity.

The most probable solution is one where there may be concentrators with delegated communicators to chain far-field devices to the central repository in efficient bulk synchronous streams in a star hierarchy for maintaining low power and high bandwidth efficiency.

I recall an Automated Meter reading (AMR) solution at the company that I worked for in the mid-90's, had the only 2way system prototype in the world which could interface millions of meters on an ISM channel in the 928MHz band with a bandwidth of 6kHz by colour-channel sectorization and regional concentrators and a latency of 1 second for real-time user power reading interfacing to the utility's head-end data base for instant readings and TOU readings sent in larger intervals daily.  Meanwhile the rest of the competitors drove around in Vans due to excessive spread spectrum noise or still have manual digital meter scanners walking around today in Ontario.  The technology was sold out to Itron, our biggest competitor in the late 90's and the company was called Iris Systems Inc in Winnipeg. After 7 design generations with the last being an embedded SoC HC11 based chipset with our own 64kbps modem RF transceiver in 6kHz channel spacing. It had to cost only $75/end unit with all the RF repeater network and headend software included, but investors with deep pockets  had run out of patience. The basic sensor was built around  IR optical rotation detection on any model of existing mechanical meters in  gas, water and electric meters, designed to last for 50-100 yrs.